# How can I clone a div and use an regEx without cloning again?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm kinda stuck.

I'm cloning the content of a p- and ul- element

```
var abc = $("div p,div ul").clone();
```

I want to change the output with a regEx replace().

It looks like

```
abc.html(abc.html().replace(/myReplace/, '$1'));
```

My problem is the output.
html-structur without

```
abc.html(abc.html().replace(/myReplace/, '$1'));
```

```
<p>Content</p>
<ul<
   <li>P1</li>
   <li>P2</li>
   <li>P3</li>
</ul>
```

html-structur with

```
abc.html(abc.html().replace(/myReplace/, '$1'));
```

```
<p>Content</p>
<ul>
<p>Content</p>
</ul>
```

How can I clone a div and replace some numbers later on without cloning again?

Answer (score 0):

'abc' is not a function. It is the resulting jQuery collection from the operations performed in the first line. Use of 'abc' thereafter does not cause more cloning.